# Key error after adding a new variable to a dataset in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataset, keyerror

I am new to Python, and this issue seems like something trivial, but I couldn't find the answer.
After adding a new variable to a dataset and checking that it is added by printing elements of the dataset, I get a Key error on this new variable when trying to refer to it. I assume there is a better way to assign a new variable to a dataset?

```
#adding 'age' variable:
for d in dataset:
        d['age'] = int((opndate - date)/60/60/24/365)
```

dataset[0]:

```
{'id': '736041664',
 'nationality': 'ESP',
 'sex': 'male',
 'dob': '10/17/69',
 'age': 46}
```

referring to it and getting a Key Error:

```
ages = [d['age'] for d in dataset]
```

KeyError: 'age'

Comment: It seems like there may be an entry in your dataset without the "age" field. Do all of the entries have the same fields?

Comment: Yes, I simplified the code a bit before posting it. The actual code is (also simple though) checks if there is an error with try - except and assigns 'Missing' to  d['age'] if an error occurs

Comment: You are right, I found the mistake!

Comment: Glad I could help!